# How is the Zeta function a "generating function"

Tags: generating-functions, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Many sources refer to zeta functions as a kind of generating function, but I have to admit: I have never fully understood what this means. (Example of such language: the first two sentences in [this book](https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Emmustata/zeta_book.pdf) read, ``Zeta functions encode the counting of certain objects of geometric, algebraic, or arithmetic behavior. What distinguishes them from other generating series are special analytic or algebraic properties.'')

In some cases, there is a clear connection: The Ihara zeta function of a graph is the exponential of the generating function for the sequence $N_l / l$, where $l$ is a natural number and $N_l$ is the number of closed cycles of length $l$ in the graph; the zeta function of a variety defined over a finite field is defined the same way, except with $N_l$ being the number of points in $\mathbb{F}_{p^l}$.

But what about *the* zeta function? Is there a way of writing $\zeta(s)$ as the exponential of some generating series?

Comment: It's the Dirichlet generating function of the constant 1 sequence. Its square is the Dirichlet generating function of the divisor counting function.

Comment: That is in the context of Dirichlet series generating function often means $\sum_{n\ge 1} a_n n^{-s}$ instead of $\sum_{n\ge 1} a_n x^n$. So $\log \zeta(s)=\sum_{p^k} \frac1k p^{-sk}$ is the generating function of (weighted) prime powers.

Comment: thanks to both of you! The second comment is along the lines of what I was looking for, especially since it shows why the zeta function is able to "detect primes". Do you have a good reference on Dirichlet generating functions? I still want to think more about how these deserve the name "generating function"